# 高さが可変の兄弟要素の残りを埋める方法

Tags: css

.hoge2の高さが可変の場合.hoge1のheightを残りでうめたいです。
display:flexを使った方法は出てくるのですが、flexを使わないでやる方法はないでしょうか？

```
<body>
  <div class="hoge1"></div>
  <div class="hoge2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox を使わない場合の主要な代替として、 [Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) を使用する方法があります。

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 100vw;
  grid-template-rows: 20vh 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}

.hoge1 {
  background: #ffa;
}

.hoge2 {
  background: #faf;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoge1"></div>
<div class="hoge2"></div>
```

また、 `height` プロパティにおいて [`calc` 関数](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/calc)を用いる方法もあります。Flexbox や Grid layout に比べると扱いづらいですが、 [CSS 変数](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)と併用することでさらに便利な機能になります。

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}

.hoge1 {
  height: 20vh;
  background: #ffa;
}

.hoge2 {
  height: calc(100vh - 20vh);
  background: #faf;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoge1"></div>
<div class="hoge2"></div>
```